# html img tag does not work with CSS sprite background

Tags: html, css

I have the following image with sprite background:

HTML:

```
<li>
    <img class="imgicons icons22" align="absmiddle" src="">
    <a href="#"></a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.icons22 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: -114px -306px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.imgicons {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url('../images/main.png') repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
}
```

Output is :

[image]

How should I remove outline border from image? I have checked this in FF/Chrome.

Comment: The border is from the broken image (no valid SRC). Use another non-img tag, like the empty A tag right under it.

Comment: Images don't have closing `</img>` tags. They're self-closing `<img />`.

Comment: @Diodeus: This is Outline Border From browser

Comment: Nope. @Diodeus is right. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gK7dP/

Comment: Everything on your page is "from the browser"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove border around sprite image in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172895/remove-border-around-sprite-image-in-chrome) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743127/chrome-safari-display-border-around-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stretch it out to fill space as needed:

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAMAAAAoyzS7AAAAA1BMVEUAAACnej3aAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAA1JREFUeNoBAgD9/wAAAAIAAVMrnDAAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
```

HTML:

```
<img align="absmiddle" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAMAAAAoyzS7AAAAA1BMVEUAAACnej3aAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAA1JREFUeNoBAgD9/wAAAAIAAVMrnDAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" class="imgicons icons22">
```

In demo border is none

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pg67S/)

[1x1 PNG Pixel generator](http://px64.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Try and change the `img` tag to a `div`.
You can't have an empty image tag and then place an image into it's background... That's not how it works. Images as backgrounds belong in a Block element.

http://jsfiddle.net/gK7dP/4/

(I increased the size of the div to accommodate the large `img`, but you get the idea...)

Answer (score 0):

Empty src doesn't mean empty image, it's invalid image (most likely, browser tries to load the same page again and display in as an image, which is impossible), that's why you get the broken image icon above the background. If you replace the empty string with some valid image URL (e.g. [base64-encoded transparent pixel](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/base64-encode-of-1x1px-transparent-gif/)), it probably will be rendered as you want. But is `img` here really needed?