# How to center image in 300px by 300px div? (Image dimensions not known)

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a div that is absolutely positioned from the top left corner of the browser that is 300px by 300px. I plan to show an image in the div but unfortunately I do not know the size of the image although I do know that the image will be 300px by 300px or smaller.

How can I create a div that has a set width and height of 300px that centers images of the same size or smaller horizontally and vertically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
#container { width: 300px; height: 300px; line-height: 300px; text-align: center; }
#container img { vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; }
```

​
[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/R2GzA/)

Comment: I didn't vote down but I got 2 down votes on the exact same answer 2 minutes ago :) Some people just like to be douches

Comment: Just beware IE with inline-block if you want [IE7 support](http://quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock).

Comment: @RobertK The `img` should be inline-block by default, and if you use a different element, there is still [the good old IE7 hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-problem-with-display-inline-block/6545033#6545033).

Comment: @ZoltanToth Yeah I see your deleted answer now. It is missing the `line-height`, but still, downvoting without a comment is not understable.

Comment: FYI : I had down voted his old answer because he didn't have the `line-height: 300px` - he deleted before I could comment.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following CSS on the div:

CSS

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff center center no-repeat;
}
```

HTML / PHP

```css
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image_url; ?>');"></div>
```

Comment: I would like to do that except that the image location is being created by PHP. Is there any way to do this while using PHP to generate the image link?

Comment: @acidic - See the second example. I would put the static CSS properties in the style sheet and only define the dynamic style property inline.

Comment: @iambriansreed What's bad practice about the solution I posted? In my opinion [`img` vs. `background-image`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335957/using-sprites-with-img-tag/4336431#4336431) should be decided on whether the image is considered content or decoration, not on which one is more practical to style. Btw I upvoted your solution.

Comment: My previous comment was a reply to a now removed comment, but I decided to leave it here because it might help future visitors to decide which technique to use in their situation.