# CSS sprite displaying all images

Tags: css

I am trying to use 1 single image file containing 4 images and display them using CSS sprite. Somehow, all 4 images are displayed. I was referring to one of the examples in w3schools.

```
<div id="ViewTypeContainer" style="float: right; margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
  <img id="calendarView" alt="" src="/Images/ButtonToggle.png" height="1" width="1"/>
  <img id="grdView" alt="" src="/Images/ButtonToggle.png" height="1" width="1" />
</div>

CSS:

#ViewTypeContainer img#calendarView {
    width:82px;
    height:82px;
    background: url('/Images/ButtonToggle.png') 0 0;
}

#ViewTypeContainer img#grdView  {
    width:82px;
    height:82px;
    background: url('/Images/ButtonToggle.png') -30px 0;
}
```

My image file is in .png format:

[image]

Can anyone spot my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure the height and width are 82px? just verify the height and width of just the image you want to display

Comment: Sprites are really meant to be used as background images to be displayed as the background of a block level element with a set width and height using X and Y postioning on the background image to display the correct portion of the sprite image.

Comment: Don't use img tags when working with sprites.

Comment: As an aside, do you need to be using ID's so frequently?

Comment: Could you add your sprite image to the question? (There's an image upload button in the question editing controls.)

Comment: Good info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335957/using-sprites-with-img-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah: your `img` tags have their `src` attributes pointing at the sprite image too.

If you want the sprite image to show up with the positioning specified in the CSS, the images need a transparent image in their `src` attribute.

Working example using your image here (I've used a [data-URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) for the transparent GIF):

- http://jsfiddle.net/7Ns8L/

And here's another example using what might be more semantic HTML (depending on what these controls actually do), i.e. no `<img>` tags:

- http://jsfiddle.net/7Ns8L/1/

Comment: Thanks Paul, so the the sole reason for needing the transparent image if I am not wrong is to remove the borders that will be displayed if no img src is specified?

Comment: @user415795: not quite. `<img>` tags have to have a non-empty `src` attribute to be valid, and if you put a non-existent URL in there, the browser will probably display a broken image icon. Therefore you need a transparent image. As @JQMRookie and commenters mentioned, you might be better off using a different element than `<img>`.

Comment: @user415795: I've added another example showing how you might do it without `<img>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. You're giving a background image to an image. So the IMG tag is displayed as normal size right over the top of your sprite. The concept of sprites is easiest applied if you work with background-position css property. You could either go through the trouble of generating a transparent .png for your IMG tag source (I wouldn't recommend it), or just replace the IMG tag with a div and give the div the same ID and CSS.